# Как менять внешний вид пункта ListView при клике на него?

Tags: android, listview, java

При разработке приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть `ListView`. Нужно, чтобы при клике на пункт, этот пункт менял свой внешний вид (цвет текста), а при повторном клике возвращался в обычное состояние. Сложность в том, что это должно сохраняться, т.е. при перезапуске приложения, внешний вид пунктов должен быть такой же как при закрытии.

P.S. Пункты списка тянутся из базы, если это чем-то поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо примерно так:
Декларируем лэйаут `TextView` (my_text_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/textView"     
             android:textColor="@color/myColor"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Заводим списочек:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(context); 
String[] items = {"Item 1","Item 2", "Item 3"}; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.my_text_view,items); 
listView.setAdapter(ad);
```

Далее при клике на элемент:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{         
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i)
     {             
          ((TextView) view).setTextColor(anyColor);  //вставляем свой цвет
     }     
});
```

Comment: все отлично, но до этого я уже додумался сам. встал другой вопрос, как сохранять, знаю, что надо писать в базу, но опять же как? и как при повторном клике возвращать адаптер в стандартное состояние.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Задайте его в установленном порядке

Comment: Задал соответствующий вопрос тут: http://hashcode.ru/questions/136725/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-android